# Ruby on Rails - Add photos to existing album or create new album

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails app where users can upload lots of photos and then organize them into albums. To start, the user uploads all their photos but they don't put them into a specific album.

I want the user to be able to click checkboxes on the photos and then have two options:

1. Add selected photos to an existing album (which I understand how to do)
   -OR-
2. Create a new album and add the photos to that one (confused)

I'm trying to figure out how to get both options to work on one page, but haven't had any luck.

EDIT: For clarification, photos can only belong to one album.

Comment: Some implementation details would be nice. Do photos and albums have a many-to-many-relationship or can each photo only be part of one album?

Comment: photos can only belong to one album

Comment: To clarify, does each photo have a single checkbox?  So the photos' individual checkboxes are checked, then one of two buttons are pressed to do either of your two actions?  Or are there two checkboxes per photo, each leading to your two actions?

Comment: One checkbox per photo, then the user either clicks "add to existing album" or "create new album"

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or are you just looking for someone to code it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest checking out the [Edit Multiple](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple) Railscast which covers updating multiple records in a form simultaneously.

Then, you could approach it by:

1) Have button_to or individual form submit elements that post to separate controller actions; one simply adding the photos to an existing album, the other calling a controller action which does an Album.create, updates it with the new set of photos, and saves it.

2) You could also take a more advanced approach using AJAX and remote javascript views (js.erb files); check out the [JQuery & AJAX Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised).  Have a popup which lets the user choose whether to save to the existing album, or a new one, then using a remote form, route their choice to the appropriate controller action, as above (plus the corresponding remote js view, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

What about having an ajax call from the second option(create a new album) that would open a pop-up that would create the album? At this point you have an album that you can assign the image to.